# Trouble retrieving Value from dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, scope

I've seen a few similar questions but I've been unable to find a suitable answer so far. I'm coding my classwork where the user will submit a name and their location to  store this information in a dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace locationserver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            RunServer(dictionary);

        }


        static void RunServer(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            Console.Clear();


            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary list -----------------");
            List<string> list = new List<string>(dictionary.Keys);
            foreach (string k in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", k, dictionary[k]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server started listening...");
                while (true)
                {

                    DoRequest(socketStream, dictionary, listener);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                RunServer(dictionary);
            }
        }


        static void DoRequest(NetworkStream inputStream, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, TcpListener listener)
        {

            string[] temp;
            string streamInput;

            streamInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (streamInput.Contains(" "))
            {
                temp = streamInput.Split(' ');
                dictionary.Add(temp[0], temp[1]);
                RunServer(dictionary);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(streamInput);
                    Console.WriteLine(dictionary[streamInput]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    RunServer(dictionary);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    RunServer(dictionary);
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```

The program operates through command prompt. If the program is only provided with the user ID, which is also the key value in the dictionary (1234 in the earlier example), then it should write back the location (library).

It prints out the dictionary once the data has been received for the purpose of error checking, yet when I try to access the key's corresponding value in the dictionary, it isn't there.

```
try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(streamInput);
                        Console.WriteLine(dictionary[streamInput]);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        RunServer(dictionary);
                    }
```

This is the block of code where I try to write the value of the provided key, however as I said, the try always fails and I'm given the error message.

Comment: I think this is way to much code and way to less explanation of what it does and what you want.

Comment: Give me an example of the data sending from the client?

Comment: MINIMAL, viable code example...

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, it's my first time using this site, should have read the rules more thoroughly.

The client operates through command prompt, so the exe would be run as follows:
"location 1234 library"
where location is the name of the exe.

This should then send this data to the server, which adds this data to the dictionary.
If the exe is only provided with the user ID, which is also the key value in the dictionary (1234 in the earlier example), then the server should send back the location (library). I've got it doing writelines instead at the moment to check errors

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with this being a client/server problem so why show client server code? The problem you are having is about storing things in data structures.

Your issue is one of scope. You need a global data structure that has scope for the whole lifetime of the server. It should not be a local entity passed through arguments. You are failing to understand scoping.

```
static Dictionary<string, string> theLocations;
```

is what you need.

---

<sub><sup>This is a student asking about the assessment I have set BTW</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `foreach (string k in list)` in `StartServer` for which you create a quite unnecessary list which is an implements and IEnumerate, which dictionary.Keys is already.

You should be able to do `foreach (var currentKey in dictionary.Keys) { [...] }`

Here is some exemple code which might help you:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    dict.Add("TheKeyString", "TheValueString");
    dict.Add("Water", "H2O");

    foreach (var entry in dict.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {entry}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Value: {dict["Water"]}");
}
```

-

```
output :>
Key: TheKeyString
Key: Water
Value: H2O
```

Comment: I understand what you mean about the list, but that's not the issue I'm trying to solve. It's my fault for being vague, but I've made a few edits to the post and hopefully now it's easier to see the problem.

Comment: @Avramovic96 Alright, I will check them out, I have also added some things, and will continue to add a second part, I will take time to review your changes before hand though, and will come back to edit.

Comment: @Avramovic96 could you give the clear nature of the value of `streamInput` in your scenario ?

Comment: `streamInput = sr.ReadToEnd();`

streamInput is just a string that takes the value of the streamreader's input, which is essentialy the data being sent over from the client.

Comment: @Avramovic96 Yeah that's what I was asking, what concrete use-case do you have for which the client is not happy ? Like, does streamInput == "1234" ? -- Have you tried checking the validity of the dictionnary client side just before sending it and verifying that you have conventional access to the keys ?